# Angular2 : How to redirect to the login page when observable subscription fails?

Tags: angular, callback, observable, redirect, canactivate

In the file ***auth-guard-service.ts***, why is the call this.router.navigateByUrl('/login') not working, while the alert message is printed ? The other call in the other file (*auth.service.ts*) works correctly.

*auth-guard-service.ts*

```
import { Injectable }          from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }          from 'rxjs';
import { Domain }              from 'domain';
import { AuthService }         from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    private domain: Domain = new Domain();

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    public canActivate(): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
            return Observable.create(
                (observer) => {
                    this.domain.isauth()
                    .subscribe(
                        (res) => {
                            observer.next(true);
                        },
                        (err) => {
                            alert('You need to be authentificated to access this content');
                            // The call to navigateByUrl below does not work. To fix.
                            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
```

*auth.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import { Router }           from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }       from 'rxjs';
import { Domain }           from 'domain';
import { ConfigService }    from './config.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    private authObject: Observable<boolean>;
    private domain: Domain = new Domain();

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    public login(login: string, password: string) : void {
        this.authObject = this.domain.auth(login, password);
        alert('Connecting... Please wait.');
        this.authObject.subscribe(
            (value) => {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('../view/dashboard');
            }
        );
    }

    public logout() : void {
        alert('Going to logout...');
        this.domain.logout();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
    }
}
```

*app.routing.ts*

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import {
    Routes,
    RouterModule
}                               from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent }       from './login';
import {
    DashboardComponent,
    ViewComponent
}                               from './view';
import { AuthGuardService }     from './services';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'view',
        component: ViewComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        children: [

            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent
            }
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'dashboard',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'view'
    }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true });
```

In the case I get an error (if the user is not connected), I just want to redirect to the login page.

Config : Angular2

Comment: Can you post your `routes` file

Comment: @vistajess Done, I edited the post

Comment: I don't see any wrong syntax or implementation in the code. Did you inject `Router` in the constructor?

Comment: @vistajess Yep. I added the content of the complete file, and also the auth service. Can the problem come from the auth.service.ts ?

Comment: 1) where do you call `logout()`? 2) What is `this.bridge.logout();`? 3) What is actually happening after the logout?

Comment: @echonax
1) I call logout() from an html file, when the user click on the logout button
2) Sorry, I corrected the post to this.domain.logout()
3) After the logout I am just redirecting with this.router.navigateByUrl('/login') (this one works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short solution (no alert()) was to replace

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

by

```
observer.next(this.router.navigate(['/login']));
```

Or, if I want to keep the alert message:

```
observer.next(false);
alert('You need to be authentificated to access this content');
this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
```

- Short explanation:

We need to call observer.next() to unblock the callback stack and execute the next callback instruction;

- More detailed explanation:

1) If you look at the code, I subscribed to an observer. In the case I got an error, there was no instruction to execute the next callback, so the stack was probably 'blocked'.

2) According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl), *navigateByUrl()* is a Promise, which works by callback. So *navigateByUrl()* probably needed the previous observer to be 'unblocked' first, before being executed in turn.

3) We may wonder why the alert() didn't have any problems to print out the error message while the two instructions were on the same block. The reason can be because Node executes the print stack (alert(), console.log(), etc...) in a different queue.

PS : I am not a master of Angular2/NodeJS/Callback/Promise/Observable so I am not sure about the answer. If you know something, please feel free to answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

> From [**angular documentation**](https://angular.io/guide/router), "Always specify the complete
>   absolute path when calling router's navigateByUrl method."

Use `router.navigate` instead:

```
public canActivate(): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
            return Observable.create(
                (observer) => {
                    this.domain.isauth()
                    .subscribe(
                        (res) => {
                            observer.next(true);
                        },
                        (err) => {
                            alert('You need to be authentificated to access this content');
                            // The call to navigateByUrl below does not work. To fix.
                            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer. The subscribe method takes 3 params, the next, the error, and the completed. Redirect once the subscribe method is completed. In this case it will go to the dashboard component.

```
login() {
    this.authService.logIn(this.model).subscribe(
      next => {
        this.alertify.success('Logged in successfully');
      },
      error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      },
      () => {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
      }
    );
  }
```